# Right usage of word "Galvanize"?

Tags: word-usage

Please consider below meaning of dictionary

> Galvanize: shock or excite (someone), typically into taking action

What is the right usage of this word? Please consider below sentences

> A sudden sound in the doorway **galvanized** her.
>   He was **galvanized** to see a column of smoke.

Is this right usage? or do I need to use differently?

I have been observed that *startle* also perfectly suits here? Does it always acceptable to replace **startle** with **galvanize**?

Comment: The typical phrase is *galvanized **into*** (doing something) suggesting that there's more than startling, with something to follow, such as an action. This is already clear from the definition the OP has quoted.

Answer (score 6):

*Galvanize* is more about being spurred to action.  That drive can take many forms- startled, surprised, horrified, excited, and more - but it's the action that's important.  So, taking your two examples, you would need to add something more to make galvanize fit.

> A sudden sound in the doorway galvanized her *into diving for cover*.
>
> He was galvanized *into running for the fire extinguisher* when he saw the column of smoke.

The examples are a little contrived/awkward, but hopefully illustrate the point.

You *can* use galvanized without expressly stating the action, but there has to be sufficient context for the reader to understand just what they were galvanized into doing.

> The attack on 9/11 galvanized the nation.

*Startled* is just being startled, with or without any resulting action, so that fits just fine into both of your examples.

Comment: In the following examples, action is suggested by the context: "Commercial relations will be galvanized by the Free Trade Agreement" or  "Galvanized by its first place, he is now focusing on the next olympics"

Answer (score 2):

The origin of the word *galvanize* lies in the work of Luigi Galvani who demonstrated that the application of electricity to a muscle would cause movement. So to be galvanized is much more than to be surprised or startled, it is to **respond** to the stimulus.

Unless there is an action involved, your subject has not been galvanized.

(Be aware also that the alternative industrial meaning -- being coated with zinc -- is not relevant here.)

Comment: "I awoke to discover that Dr McVillian was coating me with zinc; I was immediately galvanised into action."

Answer (score 0):

Galvanised has been misused by the modern media as meaning "coherent strength".
I think it was originally misused by persons believing it sounded a perfect match to their perceived meaning, especially when referring to successful sports teams.
Its only true meaning is steel that has a protective rust proof coating of zinc.

Comment: Actually, "galvanic action" is about more than just plating steel.  It is the basis of all conventional batteries, so "galvanize" can be taken (validly) to mean "electrify".